# Trying to secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt but can't access .pem files in /etc/letsencrypt/live using a non-root user

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, dockerfile, lets-encrypt

I've got a Flask app with nginx reverse proxy server in front of it. I have deployed my application on a Digital Ocean droplet. I created a user with root privileges and I'm using this user to run my application over HTTPS. I've been having problems with permissions for the .pem files located in the following path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name.com. What I do now is to copy those files to my project folder using a sudo command in the terminal and then in the nginx Dockerfile I copy them again to /etc/nginx and give this path in the configuration file. However, this is not ideal because I want my SSL certificate to be automatically renewed. I tried changing permissions from my root user using commands such as *chown -R user:user/etc/letsencrypt* but nothing worked. I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem? I want to be able to access the .pem files using the /live/my-domain-name path and to be able to renew my cert when it expires without using the root user. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Project conf file:**

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name my-domain-name.com www.my-domain-name.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }



    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  my-domain-name.com www.my-domain-name.com;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:8000;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;

            # Do not change this
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /static {
            rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
            root /static;
        }
    }
```

**Nginx Dockerfile:**

```
 FROM nginx:1.13.3

    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443

    RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

    RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    COPY project.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

    COPY fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/
    COPY privkey.pem /etc/nginx/
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is a best practice. You should not access your droplet with a root user either

You should setup the droplet with a new user with sudo grants, and remove root access completely, as explained in this guide:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04

Then you should verify the droplet and store the SSL certificates using certbot nginx plugin, like explained here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Step 5 of the last guide explains the renew certificate part.

Comment: I created a new user with sudo grants but the problem is that I can't access the .pem files. And I'm not sure if I can follow the steps from the second guide. My nginx server is running inside a Docker container.

Comment: If you want to, you can go "sudo -i" and then you can probably access them. 
Still I do not understand why you need to actually access them. I am running many droplets with nginx and SSL certificates and I never had to touch those files.

Comment: I need to specify the path to those file in my "project. conf" file. If I don't do that, I get the following error: "no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/project.conf:8". And if I specify the path to the original files, I get the "no such file or directory" error that I mentioned in my post. That's why I had to copy those files to my project folder and then copy them again to the /etc/nginx folder from my nginx Dockerfile. This is the solution I found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am afraid I do not have any, I do not work with docker containers. You sure you need that? Why do not just run nginx in the linux box? Docker seem an unnecessary complication in this scenario, but maybe I am missing some requitments for your project.